# jQuery html Attributes issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the jQuery html Attributes to wrap some words in a large piece of text, this works fine but if the text has some html tags in it, it will remove all tags. Is there a way to prevent this with the html Attributes, preventing that i strips the other tags?

piece of the code

```
var pattern = new RegExp('('+$.unique(text.replace(/\./g, '\\.').split(" ")).join("|")+")","gi");

 jQuery('searchin').each(function(i){
    var orgText = jQuery(this).text();
        orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1){
        return '<b class="highlight">' + $1 + '</b>';
    });
jQuery(this).html(orgText);
```

Comment: Can we see the contents of the variable `text`? Is it of the form `"my list of space-separated words"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work if you replace `.text()` with `.html()`, like this:

```
jQuery('p').each(function(i){
    // replaced .text() with .html()
    var orgText = jQuery(this).html();
    orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1){
        return '<strong>' + $1 + '</strong>';
    });
    jQuery(this).html(orgText);
});
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/fgGXp/)

Comment: I know the wrap, but as you can see in my code i need to wrap plain text, so certain words.

Comment: @user759235, that wasn't clear until you updated your question. Now my answer appears more or less out of context. I'll look for another solution. I recall doing the same a while back so should have something lying around :)

Comment: @user759235, updated answer! I hope this was more in line with what you were looking for ;)

Comment: This works, but not in the way that i use it, i use the code to highlight words in a piece of text, this is done true an input field, this means it live highlighting, the code above will mess up the piece of text if i enter more that 2 characters

Comment: If i change the text into html it will work, but the used code to wrap the words will be displayed to

Comment: @user759235, then you need to provide us with more details and a working test case on jsFiddle, otherwise it will be very difficult to help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

You can write [Marcus Ekwall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291956/jquery-html-attributes-issue/6292037#6292037) in a much more concise way:

```
jQuery('p').html(function(i, oldValue) {
    return oldValue.replace(pattern, function($1) {
        return '<strong>' + $1 + '</strong>';
    });
});
```